# SOQL for a collection

Tags: soql, loop, collection

Is it possible to do a "SOQL for loops" for a collection?
I want to know the number of Assets for each AccountID.

At first time I created a set that contains the AccountID and I used the SOQL for Loops to query Asset Object.

```
Set<Id> setIDAccount = new Set<Id>();
for(List<Asset> listAsset : [SELECT id, AccountId FROM Asset]){
    for(Asset a : listAsset)
        if(!setIDAccount.contains(a.AccountID)) 
            setIDAccount.add(a.AccountID);
```

At this point I want do a query for each ID present in setIDAccount and get the number of Asset for this AccountID. The simplest way is to do a for:

```
for(Id i : setIDAccount){
  System.debug([SELECT COUNT() FROM Asset WHERE AccountID =: i]);
}
```

The code is ok but I would write a better version. Is it possible not to use the FOR LOOP to iterate on set and do a query in it? How can I do it in a bulk way?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Account and Assets are related, you can use a sub query to querty/count assets using its Relationship Name.

Using a [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php), identify the Relation Name for Asset object and then perform a query.

In your code, you have written a SOQL inside a for loop. This will give SOQL [Exception](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000181404&language=en_US) error if you have more than 100 account records.

[image]

```
List<Account> accountList = [Select id, (Select Id from Assets) from Account]; // Add Where Condition fro Account
System.debug('####'+accountList);

for(Account objAccount : accountList){
   System.debug('Count Assets ###'+objAccount.Assets.size());
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's a perfect solution but I have a curiosity: Isn't possible do a "SOQL Loops" for a collection?

Comment: I'm glad, it worked for you!